# When activating virtualenv still global dependencies are installed

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I am having issues with virtualenv installations on a mac.

First change to the directory and activate virtualenv

```
cd my-project/
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

Second...my terminal changes to the virtualenv and install Django version 3.1.7

```
(venv) andrescamino@Robertos-MacBook-Pro WJKTM % pip install Django==3.1.7
```

To make sure the installation is on the virtualenv i make a pip freeze and these are the results

```
(venv) andrescamino@Robertos-MacBook-Pro WJKTM % pip freeze
asgiref==3.3.1
Django==3.1.7
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
```

Then I start the project

```
(venv) andrescamino@Robertos-MacBook-Pro WJKTM % django-admin startproject bandsite
```

However when I go to the editor and check the settings file...it still shows the version installed globally which is the 3.1.2

> Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.2.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because vscode is using your global python installation. You can see and change which python environement vscode uses from the status bar in the bottom.